# How can I echo a scraped div in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, foreach, web-scraping, screen-scraping

How do I echo and scrape a div class? I tried this but it doesn't work. I am using cURL to establish the connection.  How do I echo it? I want it just how it is on the actual page.
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTML($html);
    $selector = new DOMXPath($document);
    $anchors = $selector->query("/html/body//div[@class='resultitem']");
    //a URL you want to retrieve

```
foreach($anchors as $a) { 
    echo $a;
}
```

Comment: Could it be as simple as needing `//html` instead of `/html` ?

Comment: Nope didn't work out.  Nothing Showed up.

Comment: Are you sure the $html contains HTML?  Could your HTML be malformed?  Show us the HTML you're trying to extract.

Comment: @AndyLester this is the link http://www.classifiedads.com/search.php?keywords=couch&cid=0

Comment: @user1973004, I think Andy is suggesting that you output the `$html` variable to make sure it's being captured as you expect

Comment: yes it's being captured

Comment: I know it has something to do with the foreach part

Comment: @AndyLester please check out the new post

Comment: @user1973004 please check out the new post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neighbor, 
I just made this snippet below, that uses your logic, and some tweaks to display the specified class from the webpage in the get_contents function.
Maybe you can plug in your values and try it?

(Note: I put the error checking in there to see a few bugs. It can be helpful to use that as you tweak. )

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$url = "http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php";
$class_to_scrape="display";

$html = file_get_contents($url);
$document = new DOMDocument(); 
$document->loadHTML($html); 
$selector = new DOMXPath($document); 

$anchors = $selector->query("/html/body//div[@class='". $class_to_scrape ."']");

echo "ok, no php syntax errors. <br>Lets see what we scraped.<br>";

foreach ($anchors as $node) {
    $full_content = innerHTML($node);
   echo "<br>".$full_content."<br>" ;
}

/* this function preserves the inner content of the scraped element. 
** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349310/how-to-scrape-web-page-data-without-losing-tags
** So be sure to go and give that post an uptick too:)
**/
function innerHTML(DOMNode $node)
{
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
    $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));
  }
  return $doc->saveHTML();
}


?>
```

Comment: I think you had the echo $a wrong. Maybe it should be `$a->nodeValue`?

Comment: Thanks guys node value works.  But it just comes up with a jumbled thing of plain text.  I want to keep the format of it including links.  Is there a way I could do this?

Comment: I found the function on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349310/how-to-scrape-web-page-data-without-losing-tags). I hope it works for you.

Comment: how would I implement this?

Comment: Paste that function in by your for loop. Then in your for loop, put `echo innerHTML($a);`