# How can I echo scraped div in Table format in PHP?

Tags: php, web-scraping

i am trying to scrape table which is in div inside div and inside span, i am getting data but as whole content and not formatted as table, all i want to get all data in table format like rows and columns, how to get this output in table format? any help will be appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

**edit:** i have provided html table code which is commented because its not working

```
<html>
<div class="container">
<div class="table-responsive">

<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">

  <thead>
  <tr bgcolor='#ddbbff'>

    <th>Stations</th>
    <th>Day/Date</th>
    <th>Arrive</th>
    <th>Depart</th>
    <th>Status</th>

</tr>
  </thead>

    <tbody>


<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$url = "https://www.railmitra.com/train-running-status/12129?day=yesterday";
$class_to_scrape="well well-sm";

$html = file_get_contents($url);
$document = new DOMDocument(); 
$document->loadHTML($html); 
$selector = new DOMXPath($document); 

$anchors = $selector->query("/html/body//div[@class='". $class_to_scrape ."']");

echo "ok, no php syntax errors. <br>Lets see what we scraped.<br>";

foreach ($anchors as $node) {
$full_content = innerHTML($node);

echo "<br>".$full_content."<br>" ;

//echo "<tr>";

//echo "<td>" . $stations[] = $cells->item(0)->textContent . "</td>";
//echo "<td>" . $dayDate[] = $cells->item(1)->textContent . "</td>";
//echo "<td>" . $arr[] = $cells->item(2)->textContent . "</td>";
//echo "<td>" . $dep[] = $cells->item(3)->textContent . "</td>";
//echo "<td>" . $status[] = $cells->item(4)->textContent . "</td>";


}

/* this function preserves the inner content of the scraped element. 
** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349310/how-to-scrape-web-page-data- 
without-losing-tags
** So be sure to go and give that post an uptick too:)
**/
function innerHTML(DOMNode $node)
{
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
    $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));
  }
  return $doc->saveHTML();
 }


?>

         </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

**edit:** added html source

```
 <div class="well well-sm">
  <div class=row">
    <div class="col-7 col-md-4">
       <span class="ind-crossed">
         <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o aria-hidden="true">
               ::before
         </i>
       </span>
      " Pune Junction"
    </div>

    <div class="col-5 col-md-3">
    <span> day1 </span>
    <span> 09-sep </span>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-2 col-md-1">
     <span> 00:00 </span>
     <br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2 col-md-1">
     <span> 18:25 </span>
     <br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-8 col-md-3 text-right">
     <span class="tl-msg text-success"> Right Time </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="well well-sm">...</div>
```

Comment: Please show the source HTML you are querying by XPath.

Comment: Well don’t look at the content of the outer div wrapper then, but actually _loop over_ the individual elements contained in it …?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. We need the source and expected result. You might want an [XSLTProcessor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php)

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone do i need to provide html table code?

Comment: Yes, we cannot know what the document structure is and how exactly it should be transformed. You should provide a from-to-scenario. You can use the edit link below your question.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone sorry i didn't get that early.. added html source..

Comment: @misorude how to loop over the individual elements. can you please add some code using above reference.

Comment: Your `innerHTML` basically does that already - it loops over the children of the given node. Maybe change your XPath selector, so that you land on the `.row` element inside `.well .well-sm` directly - and then loop over the children of that, which would be the columns of the row. The `textContent` property of those nodes then would give you the text they contain (HTML elements stripped out.) If you need the contents of the span elements individually – then either loop over children on that level again, or find a different way to individually access them.

Comment: @misorude can you please add some piece of code for rows.

Comment: @misorude still not resolved, any alternate way to do the same..

Comment: Not going to write the code for you; you got a couple of hints by now, so show us what you were able to make of those so far.